# Why should I cut up debit cards that are no longer usable?

Tags: debit-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with expired cards (credit, debit, insurance cards, …)](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/what-to-do-with-expired-cards-credit-debit-insurance-cards)

I just cancelled my Chase Debit Card account, and the person advised me to cut up my old debit card.

My parents always tell me the same thing too - with credit cards I receive in the mail.

Comment: Same as http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/what-to-do-with-expired-cards-credit-debit-insurance-cards