# How to dispose of metal credit card?

Tags: credit-card

A while back I applied for and received a new credit card.  For whatever reason, this card is made of metal, as opposed to the typical plastic cards I have normally received with other accounts in the past.  Fast forward to today - I just received a replacement card in the mail, as a security precaution.

Once I activate the new card and verify it is working, I plan to dispose of the old card.  With a plastic card I would take a pair of scissors to it before throwing in the trash can, a very old habit of mine.  However, I don't think I will be able to cut this one (without creating some sharp shards and/or risking cutting myself, at least).  Are there any other measures I can/should take to destroy this card before just tossing it?  Or should I not throw it away at all, but do something else with it?

The number is the same as the new one, though the expiration date and CVC have changed, so I am a bit leery of leaving it intact in my garbage can.  What precautions are recommended (if any) when getting rid of an old, deactivated credit/debit card for which the account is still active?

Comment: When I got a metal card replaced recently, the bank sent an envelope in which the old one could be returned.  But my number changed, so I didn't mind letting the defunct one out of my hands...

Comment: Sounds more like a DIY question. My choice would be scissors for metal, rotary tool, or a drill (if I can't cut it, at least make holes in it).

Comment: Is that the "Luxury" card I keep getting offers for?  Don't know why on Earth they expect me to pay a $495 (yes, four hundred and ninety five dollars!) annual fee for a piece of metal.

Comment: Afaict amex started the trend with their centurian card for the uber-rich, other card vendors have presumablly introduced copycats for the not-so-rich.

Comment: @jamesqf That card comes with a $300 flight voucher per year, so if you fly often enough to use that then the fee is effectively $195.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I explained in [my answer to “What to do with expired cards”](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/48047/10997), I don’t think you need to worry a whole lot about it. The card is already expired and can’t be swiped/scanned anywhere successfully. Yes, the number could be visually read off the card, but crooks have much more effective ways of obtaining credit card numbers these days than digging through the garbage.

If you want to cut up your metal card in the same way that you might cut up a plastic card with scissors, use a pair of [tin snips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snips).

Answer (score 2):

When I have an old computer to dispose of, I'm always leery of allowing the hard drive to go out with the garbage or even be recycled.  When it comes to technology, I know about as much as I need to get by but I don't know how to   permanently erase the hard drive.

My solution?  I take the hard drive out, go to the curb and whack it with a hammer and chisel to get at the disk and then I cut the disk up into pieces.  Ain't no one gonna pull my data off that disk after I'm done with it (g). It's also kind of liberating to demolish things.

I surmise that a metal credit card is far thinner than a hard drive disk and would be much easier to pulverize!